# Arrows in Block Diagram are not alligned

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, block

Good evening,
i am trying to create a nice plot. Everything works fine so far, but i can not align the arrow from Node "specific" and "theoretical" to Node "cool".

Thanks for every idea.
Phil

```
  \documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}   
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}   
    \tikzset{block/.style={draw, thick, text width=2cm ,minimum height=1.7cm, align=center},   
    line/.style={-latex}     
    }  
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}


    \node[block,text width=12em,] (top) {Top}; 

    \node[block,left of=top, below of=top,minimum height=5em,  node distance=2.5cm] (a) {sub a };   

    \node[block,right of=top, below of=top, minimum height=5em, node distance=2.5cm] (b) {sub b };    

    \node[block,left of=a, below of=a,minimum height=5em,  node distance=2.5cm] (b1) {General};   

    \node[block,right of=b1,minimum height=5em,   node distance=2.5cm] (b2) {Specific }; 

    \node[block,right of=b2,minimum height=5em,   node distance=2.5cm] (b3) {theoretical}; 

    \node[block,right of=b3, minimum height=5em,  node distance=2.5cm] (b4) {More}; 

    \node[block,right of=b4,minimum height=5em,   node distance=2.5cm] (b5) {no more}; 

    \node[block,left of=b1, below of=b1, node distance=3cm,minimum height=7em] (c) {Addition};    

    \node[block,right of=c, minimum height=7
         em, node distance=3cm] (c1) {Substraction}; 

    \node[block,right of=c1,   node distance=3cm,minimum height=7
         em,text width=8em,,fill={rgb:black,1;white,8}] (c2) {Cool}; 

    \node[block,below of=b4,   node distance=3cm,minimum height=7
         em,text width=8em, fill={rgb:black,1;white,8}] (c3) {warm};  

         \node[block,below of=b5,   node distance=3cm,minimum height=7
         em,text width=4em,fill={rgb:black,1;white,8}] (c4) {cold)};  

 \draw[line] (top.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(a.north);     
 \draw[line] (top.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b.north); 
 \draw[line] (a.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b1.north); 
 \draw[line] (a.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b2.north); 
 \draw[line] (b.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b3.north); 
 \draw[line] (b.south)-- ++(0, -0.5) -|(b4.north);
 \draw[line] (b.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b5.north);
 \draw[line] (b1.south)-- ++(0, -0.4) -|(c.north);
 \draw[line] (b1.south)-- ++(0, -0.4) -|(c1.north);
 \draw[line] (b2.south)--  ++(0, -0.4) -|(c2.north);
 \draw[line] (b3.south)-- ++(0, -0.5) -|(c2.north);
 \draw[line] (b4.south)-- ++(0, -0.4) -|(c3.north);
 \draw[line] (b5.south)-- ++(0, -0.5) -|(c4.north);

\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are mainly off-topic comments. You are loading but not using `positioning`, which has the syntax `below=<distance> of ...` instead of `below of=...`. Then I'd rather use matrices for the layout. The only on-topic suggestion here is to use something like

```
south fork/.style={to path={(\tikztostart.south) --
 ++(0,-0.5) -| (\tikztotarget)}}
```

for the paths you are wondering about.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,matrix}   
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=6.5em ,
minimum height=1.7cm, align=center,text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em},   
  line/.style={-Latex}     
}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    south fork/.style={to path={(\tikztostart.south) --
 ++(0,-0.5) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
    mmat/.style={matrix of nodes,column sep=1em,nodes={block,anchor=center,#1}}]
 \node[mmat={minimum height=7em}] (row4) 
 {Addition & Subtraction & |[fill=black!20,minimum width=9em]|Cool & 
 |[fill=black!20,minimum width=9em]|Warm & |[fill=black!20]|Cold\\};
 \node[above=of row4,mmat={minimum height=5em}] (row3) 
 {General & Specific & Theoretical & More & No More\\};
 \path (row3-1-1.north) -- (row3-1-2.north) node[midway,above=1cm,block,minimum height=5em]
  (row2-1-1) {sub a};
 \path (row3-1-3.north) -- (row3-1-5.north) node[midway,above=1cm,block,minimum height=5em]
  (row2-1-2) {sub b};
 \path (row2-1-1.north) -- (row2-1-2.north) node[midway,above=1cm,block,text width=12em] 
    (top) {Top};
 \path[semithick,line,every edge/.append style={south fork}] 
 (top) foreach \X in {1,2} {edge (row2-1-\X)}
 (row2-1-1) foreach \X in {1,2} {edge (row3-1-\X)}
 (row2-1-2) foreach \X in {3,4,5} {edge (row3-1-\X)}
 (row3-1-1) foreach \X in {1,2} {edge (row4-1-\X)}
 (row3-1-2) edge (row4-1-3)
 foreach \X in {3,4,5} {(row3-1-\X) edge (row4-1-\X)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But forest might be even simpler.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}   
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
block/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=6.5em ,
minimum height=1.7cm, align=center,text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em},
forked edges,
for tree={block,edge={-latex,semithick},l sep+=1em,fork sep=1em,
    where level=3{minimum height=7em}{}}
[top
 [sub a
  [General
   [Addition]
   [Subtraction]
  ]
  [Specific,alias=specific
  ]
 ]
 [sub b
  [Theoretical
   [Cool,fill=black!20,minimum width=9em,alias=cool]
  ]
  [More
   [Warm,fill=black!20,minimum width=9em]
  ]
  [No more
   [Cold,fill=black!20,minimum width=9em]
  ]
 ]
]
\draw[-latex,semithick] (specific.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) -| (cool.north);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good morning. Thanks. I didn't know forest before. But how do I seperate text in boxes vertically here? Instead of "Cool", there is a text like "My favourite icecream: strawberry, chocolate and a lot of cream." which should be nicely seperatet.

Comment: @Phil You can use the `text width` key and just add the long text. That is, `forest` is based on Ti*k*Z and you can use the same keys as in Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram is correct, I think you just made a mistake on a numerical value, a 0.5 instead of a 0.4

```
 \documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}   
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}   
    \tikzset{block/.style={draw, thick, text width=2cm ,minimum height=1.7cm, align=center},   
    line/.style={-latex}     
    }  
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}


    \node[block,text width=12em,] (top) {Top}; 

    \node[block,left of=top, below of=top,minimum height=5em,  node distance=2.5cm] (a) {sub a };   

    \node[block,right of=top, below of=top, minimum height=5em, node distance=2.5cm] (b) {sub b };    

    \node[block,left of=a, below of=a,minimum height=5em,  node distance=2.5cm] (b1) {General};   

    \node[block,right of=b1,minimum height=5em,   node distance=2.5cm] (b2) {Specific }; 

    \node[block,right of=b2,minimum height=5em,   node distance=2.5cm] (b3) {theoretical}; 

    \node[block,right of=b3, minimum height=5em,  node distance=2.5cm] (b4) {More}; 

    \node[block,right of=b4,minimum height=5em,   node distance=2.5cm] (b5) {no more}; 

    \node[block,left of=b1, below of=b1, node distance=3cm,minimum height=7em] (c) {Addition};    

    \node[block,right of=c, minimum height=7
         em, node distance=3cm] (c1) {Substraction}; 

    \node[block,right of=c1,   node distance=3cm,minimum height=7
         em,text width=8em,,fill={rgb:black,1;white,8}] (c2) {Cool}; 

    \node[block,below of=b4,   node distance=3cm,minimum height=7
         em,text width=8em, fill={rgb:black,1;white,8}] (c3) {warm};  

         \node[block,below of=b5,   node distance=3cm,minimum height=7
         em,text width=4em,fill={rgb:black,1;white,8}] (c4) {cold)};  

 \draw[line] (top.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(a.north);     
 \draw[line] (top.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b.north); 
 \draw[line] (a.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b1.north); 
 \draw[line] (a.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b2.north); 
 \draw[line] (b.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b3.north); 
 \draw[line] (b.south)-- ++(0, -0.5) -|(b4.north);
 \draw[line] (b.south)-- ++(0, -0.25) -|(b5.north);
 \draw[line] (b1.south)-- ++(0, -0.4) -|(c.north);
 \draw[line] (b1.south)-- ++(0, -0.4) -|(c1.north);
 \draw[line] (b2.south)--  ++(0, -0.4) -|(c2.north);
 \draw[line] (b3.south)-- ++(0, -0.4) -|(c2.north); % <- here
 \draw[line] (b4.south)-- ++(0, -0.4) -|(c3.north);
 \draw[line] (b5.south)-- ++(0, -0.5) -|(c4.north);

\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for attempt. I tried this, but unfortunately didn't work